# Running functions in a sequence in Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I'm creating a Phonegap app and I want a few functions to run in sequence using javascript/jQuery. Like in the following sequence.

1. Propagate database (create tables and insert initial data) - propagateDB()
2. Select data from a table which has that initially inserted data - selectRecs()

And I'm confused with in which event should I run each of these functions. Such as in onDeviceReady, mobileinit, document.ready like wise. Sometimes selecting data does not work when used in these onDeviceReady.

Answer (score 0):

- onDeviceReady fires when the device's API elements are ready for access
- mobileinit fires when jQuery Mobile is ready
- document.ready fires when the DOM has completely laid out

You should be able to access (read or write) your database at anytime after onDeviceReady fires. I would load the UI first (wait for document.ready) then access the database to display your data. You can put data into the database onDeviceReady though.